# Draw polygon in polygons (regular polygons)

Tags: python, polygon, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is my code that draws regular polygons:

```
import turtle

tr = turtle.Turtle()

tr.lt(150)
for x in range(3,13):
    for i in range(x):
        tr.fd(80)
        tr.lt(360//x)

turtle.done()
```

This is my output:
[image: actual output]

But my expected output is:
[image: expected output]

Can you help me?

Comment: You probably want to move the turtle at thee end of the polygon, so the ends won't be connected

Comment: Looks like you need to calculate the radius offset and move in/out from the center if you want them all concentric. Currently you're always starting the first/last vertex at the same point.

Comment: @mousetail 
This is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed in the comments

You probably want to move the turtle at thee end of the polygon, so the ends won't be connected

- @mousetail

Looks like you need to calculate the radius offset and move in/out from the center if you want them all concentric. Currently you're always starting the first/last vertex at the same point.

- @CrazyChunky

After having a quick look in the [turtle methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle-methods)

I came up with this

```
import turtle
import math
tr = turtle.Turtle()

r0 = 20
tr.lt(150)
for x in range(3,13):
    points = [
        (r0 * (x-1) * math.cos(k*2*math.pi/x),
         r0 * (x-1) * math.sin(k*2*math.pi/x))
        for k in range(1,x+1)
    ]
    tr.penup() # avoid creating a line connecting two polygons
    tr.goto(*points[-1])
    tr.pendown() # draw one polygon
    for tx, ty in points:
        tr.goto(tx,ty);
turtle.done()
```

[image]

PS.: I have never heard about this module before, and it was a surprise to see that it was installed in my machine.

Comment: The syntax of this code is a bit strange and complicated for me.
for example, what is r0?

Comment: `r0` is only a constant that was not in the code I pasted, updated.

Comment: About the syntax, that's python syntax hehe

Comment: Turtle is part of Python's standard library, so it's always installed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple-minded solution using `circle()` to do our work for us:

```
import turtle
from math import pi

for sides in range(3, 13):
    radius = 40 * sides / pi

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.circle(radius, steps=sides)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]